# Admob on android Why do I get "AFMA_buildAdURL is not defined"?

Tags: android, admob

See my last comment for solution.

I am trying to use admob for an Android application. I have tried pure code instantiation and xml and code instantiation. When I try to load the ad, I get the following:

```
10:06:52.575: I/Ads(4827): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("HASHEDIDFORMYPHONE") to get test ads on this device.
10:06:52.585: I/Ads(4827): Starting ad request.
10:06:54.047: E/Ads(1596): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_buildAdURL is not defined (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/:1)
10:07:53.130: W/Ads(4827): Timed out waiting for ad response.
10:07:53.130: I/Ads(4827): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
10:07:53.130: W/Ads(4827): Failed to load ad: 2
```

Note that the Uncaught Ref Error happens less than two seconds after trying to load the ad.

Here is xml from my layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/search_layout_top_height" >

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapAdInsert"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/search_layout_ad_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/search_layout_ad_height"
            android:layout_below="@id/layoutOptions"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
                     android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MYADMOBID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER" />
        </RelativeLayout>           
</FrameLayout>
```

And finally, here's the code:

```
//AdMob
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedStateInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedStateInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_overlay);

    // AdMob Create an ad.
    adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("HASHEDIDFORMYPHONE")
        .build();
    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    // End of AdMob
```

I have made signed apks (release mode) and tried debug mode; no difference. I've not been able to find any answers to why AFMA_buildAdURL is undefined.

Any insight is much appreciated. Thanks!
(And this is only my second question ever on SO. If I am violating cultural norms here, please correct me and accept my apologies.)

Additional info: I have tried this on two Samsung SIII's. Same results.

Final update: I asked this question on the Google Groups admob forum. Eric L., who I believe works for AdMob, indicated there was no problem with my code. I turned off wifi on my phone and used my (xubuntu) laptop as a bluetooth PAN for the phone; I then used wireshark (and I ran it as root and was not afraid) to capture all the bluetooth network traffic from the phone. A quick analysis of the trace indicated that the DNS lookup from the phone for googleads.g.doubleclick.net was failing almost instantly. 30 minutes of emailing with our (sharp) IT guy revealed that someone long ago had poisoned that domain in order to ad block. I can now see ads. I sure hope someone else who gets the AFMA_buildAdURL error is helped by this.

**Short version:** Check to see if your network or android device is blocking ad URLs.

Comment: Post the reference to that post in Google Groups as an answer.

Comment: Clarify your demand: Do you want me to post the information in this post to the Google Groups board, or include here a link to the post I made in Google Groups?

Comment: Post your answer and mark as an answer.